# Region/counties google place codes?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

Any one know in which ISO format google places returns the place object short_name for regions ?

I have this code:

```
var place = places.getPlace();
    var type = place.address_components[0].types[0];
switch(type) {
    case 'country':         document.getElementById('country').value=place.address_components[0].short_name;
        break;
    case 'locality':
        document.getElementById('town').value=place.address_components[0].long_name;
        break;
    default: //when is not a country or a city
           document.getElementById('regioncode').value=place.address_components[0].short_name
```

;

In case is a region/county it gets the shor_name of it, but is some cases it returns a code like searching for "Balearic Islands, Spain" it return "PM" (which stands for ISO 3166-2:ES), but if I search "Kalmar län, Sweden" I get exactly the same for short_name as long_name which is "Kalmar County" instead of "H" (which stands for ISO 3166-2:SE)so my question is: Why Google sometimes return ISO 3166-2 values for regions/counties and sometimes the long_name value, is it any logic behind this? Can I force to ONLY return ISO values for short_names ??? thank you

Answer (score 0):

According to [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/details?hl=en):

> short_name is an abbreviated textual name for the address component,
>   if available. For example, an address component for the state of
>   Alaska may have a long_name of "Alaska" and a short_name of "AK" using
>   the 2-letter postal abbreviation.

The Key word here is "if available". Kalmar County must not have a short name